# Why got an unexpected keyword argument 'num_workers' with TypeError: __init__()?

Tags: python, automation, napalm

```
from nornir import InitNornir
from nornir_napalm.plugins.tasks import napalm_get
from nornir_utils.plugins.functions import print_result
import json

def prettyPrintDictionary(dict):
  print(json.dumps(dict, indent=2))


nr = InitNornir(config_file="/home/python/nornir-scripts/config.yaml")

print(nr.inventory.hosts)


prettyPrintDictionary(nr.inventory.get_hosts_dict())
```

```
# config.yaml
inventory:
  plugin: SimpleInventory
  options:
    host_file: '/home/python/nornir-scripts/inventory/hosts.yaml'
    group_file: '/home/python/nornir-scripts/inventory/groups.yaml'
    defaults_file: '/home/python/nornir-scripts/inventory/defaults.yaml'
runner:
   plugin: threaded
   options:
     num_workers: 100
```

Help please I cant understand how to initialize nornir
I try to do it with guide and it also have mistakes.
Now I have this mistake...

Comment: What is in your `config.yaml` file?

Comment: its on the bottom of code

Comment: I have this Traceback

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'num_workers'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://nornir.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/initializing_nornir.html), the `num_workers` key should be inside the `runner.options` key. Add it to the `options` key and try again:

```
inventory:
  plugin: nornir.plugins.inventory.simple.SimpleInventory
  options:
    host_file: 'inventory/hosts.yaml'
    group_file: 'inventory/groups.yaml'
    defaults_file: 'inventory/defaults.yaml'
runner:
   plugin: threaded
   options:
     num_workers: 100
```

Comment: I did it but still have problems(

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'num_workers'

Comment: wrote down the changes

Comment: now I have this mistake
AttributeError: 'Inventory' object has no attribute 'get_hosts_dict'

Comment: wrote down the changes

Comment: In the nornir 3.x versions, `get_hosts_dict()` has been removed. You need to use `nr.inventory.dict()`

Comment: Amazing its work) Thanks soo much!!! ) I try to make this task for many weeks by myself

Comment: Glad I could help :)